# how to time a certain part of an executable?

Tags: command-line, monitoring

I was looking around on the internet to find if there was already a way to time a certain part of an executable/script to see how long that part takes, but all that I find is more for outside  the file. So I want to input a line that starts a timer and at the end of the part stops the timer and shows me the elapsed time, not the whole thing but just a part.
example:

```
  #!/bin/sh
    IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"
    BLOCKEDIPS_XS=/root/iptables/iptables/blockxs.zone
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES --delete-chain
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
$IPTABLES -F -t mangle
$IPTABLES -F -t nat
$IPTABLES -X
timer start
/bin/egrep -v "^#|^$" $BLOCKEDIPS_XS | while IFS= read -r ip
do
    # Append everything to droplist
    $IPTABLES -A droplist -i eth0 -s $ip -j LOG --log-prefix " Drop IP List blockxs "
    $IPTABLES -A droplist -i eth0 -s $ip -j DROP
done <"$BLOCKEDIPS_XS"
timer stops, shows elapsed time
```

Comment: Please do not add version tags unless the question is version specific. Nothing in this question is specific to any particular version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `time` that operates on command groups and the `SECONDS` variable are both bash features, not in sh. With sh, you can get the timestamps at the two points using the `date` command, and then get the difference. `date +%s` will give the time in seconds since the epoch.

```
# timer start
start=$(date +%s)
/bin/egrep -v "^#|^$" $BLOCKEDIPS_XS | while IFS= read -r ip
do
    # Append everything to droplist
    $IPTABLES -A droplist -i eth0 -s $ip -j LOG --log-prefix " Drop IP List blockxs "
    $IPTABLES -A droplist -i eth0 -s $ip -j DROP
done <"$BLOCKEDIPS_XS"
# timer stops, shows elapsed time
echo $(( $(date +%s) - start ))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can time part of a bash script by using [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foo"
sleep 1

time { 
sleep 2
echo "bar"
sleep 3
}

sleep 1
echo "baz"
```

Ex.

```
$ ./somescript.sh 
foo
bar

real    0m5.006s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.001s
baz
```

Grouping with a subshell (i.e. parentheses in place of braces) should also work.

Comment: In this case, a group might not even be needed - the bash `time` keyword works on pipelines, and the part that OP wants to time is a single pipeline... But they are using sh, so the external time command will be used, making it more complicated.

Comment: @muru good catch - I missed that the OP was using `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to put the `time` command in front of the command you are running. For example:

```bash
$ time locate display-auto
/etc/cron.d/display-auto-brightness
/home/rick/Downloads/display-auto-brightness
/home/rick/Pictures/display-auto-brightness conky.png
/home/rick/Pictures/display-auto-brightness systray.png
/home/rick/Pictures/display-auto-brightness-config 1.png
/home/rick/Pictures/ps display-auto-brightness.png
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/display-auto-brightness
/mnt/e/etc/cron.d/display-auto-brightness
/mnt/e/lib/systemd/system-sleep/display-auto-brightness
/mnt/e/usr/local/bin/display-auto-brightness
/usr/local/bin/display-auto-brightness

real    0m0.826s
user    0m0.803s
sys     0m0.016s
```

We are using the `locate` command to find all the filenames with `display-auto` in the names. Simply insert the `time` command in front of the command.

---

### Getting time for portion of script

You can use the `$SECONDS` variable inside your script to get the time for a portion of it. For example:

```bash
SECONDS=0
/bin/egrep -v "^#|^$" $BLOCKEDIPS_XS | while IFS= read -r ip
do
    # Append everything to droplist
    $IPTABLES -A droplist -i eth0 -s $ip -j LOG --log-prefix " Drop IP List blockxs "
    $IPTABLES -A droplist -i eth0 -s $ip -j DROP
done <"$BLOCKEDIPS_XS"
timer stops, shows elapsed time
BlockTime=$SECONDS
echo "Total time to block IPs: $BlockTime Seconds"
```

In this code the `SECONDS` is reset to zero and then obtained after a lengthy process occurs.

Comment: yes that is what i see mostly but now i need it in a file like if you were to use the comand `nano (filename)` so not to run with nano but put it in the file you are working on and once the file is execited with the `./(filename)`

Comment: @delfiler I added the `SECONDS` variable to get time for portion of script only.

Comment: so if i am right i should put `SECONDS=0` first then put  `rsyncTime=$SECONDS`  at the end, right?

Comment: @delfiler Correct!

Comment: sad to inform that isn't not working

Comment: @delfiler I changed the answer to use your code.

Comment: okay it works but it doesn't count i get this `Total time to block IPs: 0 Seconds` when i did put it at the start of the line i wanted to start from

Comment: @delfiler Approximately how many seconds should it be displaying?

Comment: i guess a miss communication happened but it shouldn't display for a time, no. It should show the time elapsed from the point the timer starts and until it stops and it should show this at the point the timer is stopped